# Is there obstruction of justice in stopping McGahn?

Tags: united-states, trump-impeachment

A judge determined that McGahn (former white-house counsel) must testify despite the directions from Trump that he should not. Is this being looked at as possible obstruction of Justice? Or simply an innocent legal misunderstanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The judge's determination is not the final word on the matter, as the ruling may be appealed.  But in any event, a good faith effort to pursue legal avenues to prevent a witness from testifying does not constitute [obstruction of justice](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1505), which criminalizes things like using force or threats to prevent testimony, not legal arguments about the validity of a subpoena.

Comment: Why wouldn't any attempt to prevent a witness from testifying be considered obstruction, even if it's not specifically criminal?  The Constitution does not require that the grounds for impeachment be criminal acts.  They can be simply "misdemeanor", which in the language of the 18th century means "bad behavior", not the current usage of a minor criminal offense.  (In addition, it brings in the "If he's not guilty, why does he act guilty?" argument :-))

Comment: @jamesqf the congress can name whatever charges it likes in articles of impeachment and define them however it likes.  I assumed that the term "obstruction of justice" in the question denoted the statutory crime, since there was nothing in the question to suggest otherwise (though I did overlooked the "trump impeachment" tag).  Still, I doubt that efforts to work within the legal system would gain much traction as potentially impeachable acts.

Comment: I suppose it depends on your point of view.  I would think that trying to use the legal system by asserting nonsense arguments about Executive staff not having to respond to Congressional subpoenas constitutes a misdemeanor. (In the Constitutional sense of the word.) As the judge said, "Presidents are not kings".